# Unexpected output while sorting the list of IP address

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort the list of ipaddress from the following list.

```
IPlist= ['209.85.238.4', '216.239.51.98', '64.233.173.198', '64.3.17.208', '64.233.173.238']
```

#1st case

```
tmp1 = [list (map (str, ip.split("."))) for ip in IPlist]

tmp1.sort()
print(tmp1)
```

When I run this snippet. I got the following output.

```
[['209', '85', '238', '4'], ['216', '239', '51', '98'], ['64', '233', '173', '198'], ['64', '233', '173', '238'], ['64', '3', '17', '208']]
```

#second case

```
tmp = [tuple (map (int, ip.split("."))) for ip in IPlist]
# print(tmp)

tmp.sort ()
print(tmp)
```

When I run the second case,I got the following output.

```
[(64, 3, 17, 208), (64, 233, 173, 198), (64, 233, 173, 238), (209, 85, 238, 4), (216, 239, 51, 98)]
```

The only thing that I found the difference is the conversion to either string or int function using above function. But even if the intial values are string, doesnt sort() function works in the same way?

For eg:

```
lst = ['23', '33', '11', '7', '55']
 
# Using sort() function with key as int
lst.sort(key = int)
 
print(lst)
Output: 

['7', '11', '23', '33', '55']
```

Comment: Clearly not. `str(11) < str(7)`

Comment: I dont understand, the answer says `['7', '11', '23', '33', '55']`, so clearly '7' < '11'

Comment: No; `int('7') < int('11')`. That's what `key=int` does.

Comment: [inet_aton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton) to sort IPv4 addresses. `sorted(IPlist, key=inet_aton)`

Comment: you could use sort with a key formed of a tuple of ints given that your addresses contain multiple integers separted by periods: `sorted(IPlist,key=lambda a:tuple(map(int,a.split('.'))))`.  The tuple comparisons will use numeric values but the output will remain a list of the original strings

Answer (score 7):

This happens because the addresses are being compared as strings, which are sorted lexically - converting them to numbers will sort the way you expect

```py
>>> sorted(["11", "2"])
['11', '2']
>>> sorted([11, 2])
[2, 11]
```

However, it's probably better overall to use the builtin [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html), which can sort the addresses correctly for you and has useful methods and comparisons for IP addresses (such as checking whether an IP is a member of a subnet or providing the network address of an interface with an IP and mask)

```py
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip_list = ['209.85.238.4', '216.239.51.98', '64.233.173.198', '64.3.17.208', '64.233.173.238']
>>> sorted(ipaddress.ip_address(a) for a in ip_list)
[IPv4Address('64.3.17.208'), IPv4Address('64.233.173.198'), IPv4Address('64.233.173.238'), IPv4Address('209.85.238.4'), IPv4Address('216.239.51.98')]
```